# Accessing session store in service functions

Tags: authentication, svelte, svelte-store, sveltekit

I try to create pure functions or at least some service classes for accessing backend apis with typed methods. For authentication I use cookies.

For client requests cookie authentication works on the fly, but for ssr I have to add a cookie header as part of the request while using `fetch`.

I have the required token already in the session, but if I try to access to the session via `import { session } from '$app/stores';` outside of a component, I got
`Function called outside component initialization`.

One option could be to add on each SSR api function call the cookie header manually as parameter, but this won't seam to be a clean way.

Does someone have an idea on how access the session outside of a component, or are there any possible ways to define service classes containing access to stores (incl. session store) which's functions are usable across components?

I would like to use something like:

```
export async function load({ page, fetch, session, context }) {
    let me = (await service.getLoggedInUser())?.username ?? "not logged in";
    // or:
    me = (await getLoggedInUser())?.username ?? "not logged in";
    // ...
}
```

Instead of:

```
export async function load({ page, fetch, session, context }) {
    let me = (await service.getLoggedInUser(session))?.username ?? "not logged in";
    // or:
    me = (await getLoggedInUser(session)())?.username ?? "not logged in";
    // ...
}
```

Would be great if someone can provide a hint to continue.

Thank you in advance.

Ramazan

Comment: I must be missing something, but isn't adding the session as an argument more 'pure' considering in that case the function doesn't depend on any outside values ?

Comment: Yeah fair enough, thanks for addition, the term "pure" function was not right. It should not be a pure function, instead let's call them service functions :)
It's ok to define them and export from a service or component, but shall be accessible from other components.